# Codeigniter Flashdata - Not Displaying My Message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using [this](http://www.christopherimrie.com/blog/making_the_codeigniter_session_class_more_useful_with_custom_flashdata) extension of the CI_Session Class. To create flash data and style them using TW Bootstrap. However when I go to pass the "Success" message to the view it's just not loading in at all.

I have had a good luck but no joy with it.

My Controller looks like this..

```
// Set form Validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim|is_unique[films.title]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['page_title'] = 'Add New DVD';

        $this->load->view('_partials/_header', $data);

        $this->load->view('_partials/_menu');

        $data['genres'] = $this->genre_model->get_genres();

        $data['classification'] = $this->classification_model->get_classifications();

        $this->load->view('create', $data);

        $this->load->view('_partials/_footer'); 
    }
    else
    {
        // Insert into DB
        $film_data = array
        (
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'genre_id' => $this->input->post('genre'),
            'classification_id' => $this->input->post('classification')
        );

        $this->film_model->create($film_data);

        $this->session->set_success_flashdata('feedback', 'Success message for client to see');

        redirect('dvd');
```

and my View is....

```
<?php $this->session->flashdata('feedback'); ?>
```

So when I insert a new item to the DB, The Model runs, The redirect runs but the "set_success_flashdata" doesnt.

The MY_session library is set to load automatically as per CI's default config.

How do I get this damn Flash Message to show ::( ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not `set_success_flashdata` it is just `set_flashdata`.

Change in Controller :

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Success message for client to see');
```

View is just as it is :

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('feedback');
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Although I fail to see the point of this particular extension, the answer is simple enough.

You are not echoing the data from the Session Library.

The correct way to echo flashdata is like so:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('feedback'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi there @Repox - When you say fail to see the point, Could you explain more please? Are you referring to the library, or the flashdata extension? Also I have tried echo and that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: @StuBlackett I'm referring to the flashdata extension. Basically, you could just use `$this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', '<p class="error">The message to the client</p>');` where you need it. Or even better - create a helper. Extending the core library seems like overkill.
It should be enough to echo the flash data. Try to make sure the flashdata works without the extension.

Comment: Interesting... The flash data is not working without the extension.

Comment: Now you know where to start ;)